# Python DateTime In and DateTime Out - Calculations regarding a time Window

Tags: python, date, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe of two DateTime Object columns (one representing a surgery clocking in and the other when it is clocked out). For each row (ie case), I need to create a column of total time within business hours (07:00 - 17:30) and another column of total time outside of business hours. I am not sure the best approach.

Reproducible segment of my dataframe:

```
    Actual Room In DateTime Actual Room Out DateTime
0   2013-11-01 02:16    2013-11-01 04:35
1   2016-06-10 16:42    2016-06-10 19:28
2   2014-12-13 09:15    2014-12-13 10:55
3   2014-01-03 19:46    2014-01-03 22:54
4   2015-01-12 18:13    2015-01-12 19:58
5   2017-03-24 18:55    2017-03-24 19:57
6   2015-08-07 18:46    2015-08-07 19:42
7   2016-03-18 20:43    2016-03-19 00:40
8   2017-02-23 15:21    2017-02-23 17:35
9   2013-11-29 17:08    2013-11-29 17:42
10  2014-05-28 18:17    2014-05-28 19:12
11  2017-07-15 17:04    2017-07-15 18:19
12  2017-02-16 09:14    2017-02-16 21:29
13  2014-07-11 12:04    2014-07-11 17:40
14  2017-07-05 12:27    2017-07-05 20:08
15  2014-08-18 17:55    2014-08-18 19:50
16  2015-01-23 15:41    2015-01-23 19:41
17  2015-01-12 16:59    2015-01-12 17:49
18  2014-02-23 11:24    2014-02-23 15:06
19  2017-09-21 13:40    2017-09-21 18:11
```

```
pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

The maximum amount of time between the two columns is:

```
df['Room Difference'] = df['Actual Room Out DateTime'] - df['Actual Room In DateTime']
max(df['Room Difference'])
```

```
Timedelta('1 days 01:17:00')
```

Which helps me think about the problem and the algorithm I want to write.

I guess it would go something like this (as pseudocode):

```
if 00:00:00 <= 'Actual Room In DateTime' < 07:00:00 and 00:00:00 <= 'Actual Room Out DateTime' < 07:00:00:
     'After-hours' = 'Actual Room Out DateTime' - 'Actual Room In DateTime'
... to cover all the possible cases.
```

Is there an easier way or some sort of framework/tool for this exact kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Subtract In time from Business Starting time , to get outside hours before day start

Subtract Out time from Business End time, to get outside hours after day end

Subtract In time from Out time, to get total hours of surgery

Add the two outside hours, to get total outside hours

Subtract total outside hours from total hours, to get total within business hours

Make a separate column for every calculation